# Blank map tiles - Error 410 gone (Mapbox & Leaflet JS)

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapbox, client-side-scripting

I am using Leaflet JS and MapBox to create a map. My browser displays as below:

[image: Blank map tiles with MapBox]

The map does not show at all, my map tile is blank. The errors that I get in the dev tools console is:

[image: Error messages in console]

```
GET https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/9/123/183.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXl2ZXJkaWN0IiwiYSI6ImNrZmoyYmpuNDB1eHYycG16bms0aHN2ZWwifQ.w0DRp5yDUHxa2RJa0aDRlQ 410 (Gone)
Image (async)       
createTile  @   TileLayer.js:158
_addTile    @   GridLayer.js:812
_update     @   GridLayer.js:709
_setView    @   GridLayer.js:570
_resetView  @   GridLayer.js:526
 onAdd      @   GridLayer.js:162
_layerAdd   @   Layer.js:114
whenReady   @   Map.js:1465
addLayer    @   Layer.js:176
addTo       @   Layer.js:52
(anonymous) @   maps.js:16
```

The `maps.js:16` above references the last line `.addTo(map)` in the `maps.js` code snippet below:

```
let coordinates = [ 44.96, -93.2 ] 
let zoomLevel = 9
let map = L.map("college-map").setView(coordinates, zoomLevel)

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery &copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets',
accessToken: 'your-access-token'
}).addTo(map)
```

How do I fix this error and display the map successfully?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Mapbox changed the url schema from:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'
}).addTo(map);
```

To:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
    tileSize: 512,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    accessToken: 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'
}).addTo(map);
```

The url `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}` and the `{id: 'mapbox/streets-v11'}` changed.

Doc: [Mapbox Leaflet Implementaton](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/#will-the-apis-return-an-error-when-classic-styles-are-no-longer-supported) (On the right side is a switch with before and after(now)).

Url params: [Static Tiles Style](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-tiles)

**Default [Styles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#styles)**

The new default style Ids:

- mapbox/streets-v11
- mapbox/outdoors-v11
- mapbox/light-v10
- mapbox/dark-v10
- mapbox/satellite-v9
- mapbox/satellite-streets-v11

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually provides the fix as well as detailed description and references.

Answer (score 12):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

> "410 Gone client error response code indicates that access to the
> target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that
> this condition is likely to be permanent."

If you open your link https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/9/123/183.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibXl2ZXJkaWN0IiwiYSI6ImNrZmoyYmpuNDB1eHYycG16bms0aHN2ZWwifQ.w0DRp5yDUHxa2RJa0aDRlQ in the browser, you will get this:

> {"message":"Classic styles are no longer supported; see
> https://blog.mapbox.com/deprecating-studio-classic-styles-d8892ac38cb4
> for more information"}

See also this:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/#will-the-apis-return-an-error-when-classic-styles-are-no-longer-supported

Answer (score 4):

Mapbox `mapbox.streets` tiles was deprecated for new static styles api.

Old url: `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=`

New url: `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=`

Also replace `mapbox.streets` for `mapbox/streets-v11` in id parameter of `L.tileLayer()` object.

Official docs: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-tiles