# Leaflet mapbox.dark theme is not working, how can get dark theme

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have been using leaflet to show map in my website, which is in dark mode, but until recently, I found dark mode in leaflet map stopped working at all,

This is my code,

```
this.map = L.map('dv-map', {
            minZoom: this.props.minZoom,
            maxZoom: this.props.maxZoom
        }).setView(this.props.center, this.props.initLevel);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + this.props.mapBoxToken, {
                maxZoom: this.props.maxZoom,
                id: 'mapbox.dark'
            })
            .addTo(this.map);
```

I tested other id, such as mapbox.streets, mapbox.satellite etc., still fine, only dark is not working at all.

Can anybody tell me how to prvoide dark mode for the leaflet map?

Thanks

Comment: Mapbox chaged theier tiles system, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262141/8283938

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blank map tiles - Error 410 gone (Mapbox & Leaflet JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073635/blank-map-tiles-error-410-gone-mapbox-leaflet-js)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
    tileSize: 512,
    maxZoom: this.props.maxZoom,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    id: 'mapbox/dark-v10',
    accessToken: this.props.mapBoxToken
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation about what is different and why it would work better.